# eBPF: default bpf programs/maps?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, bpf, ebpf

I'm facing a strange behaviour of `bpf` with the latest `net-next` kernel. With all the BPF kernel options enabled (including `CONFIG_BPF_JIT_ALWAYS_ON`) and without *any* `bpf` programs loaded, `bpftool` reports the following:

```
# ./bpftool prog show
2: cgroup_skb  tag 7be49e3934a125ba
        loaded_at Feb 05/10:17  uid 0
        xlated 296B  jited 229B  memlock 4096B  map_ids 2,3
3: cgroup_skb  tag 2a142ef67aaad174
        loaded_at Feb 05/10:17  uid 0
        xlated 296B  jited 229B  memlock 4096B  map_ids 2,3
4: cgroup_skb  tag 7be49e3934a125ba
        loaded_at Feb 05/10:17  uid 0
        xlated 296B  jited 229B  memlock 4096B  map_ids 4,5
5: cgroup_skb  tag 2a142ef67aaad174
        loaded_at Feb 05/10:17  uid 0
        xlated 296B  jited 229B  memlock 4096B  map_ids 4,5
6: cgroup_skb  tag 7be49e3934a125ba
        loaded_at Feb 05/10:17  uid 0
        xlated 296B  jited 229B  memlock 4096B  map_ids 6,7
7: cgroup_skb  tag 2a142ef67aaad174
        loaded_at Feb 05/10:17  uid 0
        xlated 296B  jited 229B  memlock 4096B  map_ids 6,7
#
# ./bpftool map show
2: lpm_trie  flags 0x1
        key 8B  value 8B  max_entries 1  memlock 4096B
3: lpm_trie  flags 0x1
        key 20B  value 8B  max_entries 1  memlock 4096B
4: lpm_trie  flags 0x1
        key 8B  value 8B  max_entries 1  memlock 4096B
5: lpm_trie  flags 0x1
        key 20B  value 8B  max_entries 1  memlock 4096B
6: lpm_trie  flags 0x1
        key 8B  value 8B  max_entries 1  memlock 4096B
7: lpm_trie  flags 0x1
        key 20B  value 8B  max_entries 1  memlock 4096B
#
```

This is what the program contains:

```
# ./bpftool prog dump xlated id 2
   0: (bf) r6 = r1
   1: (69) r7 = *(u16 *)(r6 +192)
   2: (b4) (u32) r8 = (u32) 0
   3: (55) if r7 != 0x8 goto pc+14
   4: (bf) r1 = r6
   5: (b4) (u32) r2 = (u32) 16
   6: (bf) r3 = r10
   7: (07) r3 += -4
   8: (b4) (u32) r4 = (u32) 4
   9: (85) call bpf_skb_load_bytes#6169312
  10: (18) r1 = map[id:2]
  12: (bf) r2 = r10
  13: (07) r2 += -8
  14: (62) *(u32 *)(r2 +0) = 32
  15: (85) call bpf_map_lookup_elem#73712
  16: (15) if r0 == 0x0 goto pc+1
  17: (44) (u32) r8 |= (u32) 2
  18: (55) if r7 != 0xdd86 goto pc+14
  19: (bf) r1 = r6
  20: (b4) (u32) r2 = (u32) 24
  21: (bf) r3 = r10
  22: (07) r3 += -16
  23: (b4) (u32) r4 = (u32) 16
  24: (85) call bpf_skb_load_bytes#6169312
  25: (18) r1 = map[id:3]
  27: (bf) r2 = r10
  28: (07) r2 += -20
  29: (62) *(u32 *)(r2 +0) = 128
  30: (85) call bpf_map_lookup_elem#73712
  31: (15) if r0 == 0x0 goto pc+1
  32: (44) (u32) r8 |= (u32) 2
  33: (b7) r0 = 1
  34: (55) if r8 != 0x2 goto pc+1
  35: (b7) r0 = 0
  36: (95) exit
#
```

The funny thinks is that I have not loaded any `eBPF` program explicitly. I wonder if there's now a default `eBPF` blob in the kernel, that shows up?

This happens right after the machine has booted. The only difference between this system and another (running the same kernel and options, and where I don't see this issue with multiple cgroup_skb programs) is the presence of `/sys/fs/cgroup/unified` cgroup2 FS. I don't know if this is related to my issue,  but I don't know how to disable `/sys/fs/cgroup/unified`, un-mounting is not allowed.

Comment: Not that I am aware of. Could it be possible that you are running some program on the machine that would be attaching eBPF programs to cgroups? Or does this happen just after you boot the machine, without anything specific running?

Comment: I'd be tempted to have a look at sytemd about this, but I'm not totally sure this is the culprit. I may try to have a look if I can.

Comment: Needs further investigation, but this systemd PR could be related: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/6764

Comment: Ah, so that _was_ systemd after all :-). The “Can we shut it down” part is probably easier to sort out, but my knowledge of systemd being very limited, I can't help further on this one.

Comment: Yes, _systemd_ is a culprit, for now I downgraded to earlier version which doesn't have IPAccess feature; _systemd_ is so fat to quickly understand it and tweak accordingly ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Qeole was suspecting, this is coming from systemd, in particular systemd v235 introduced IP access control eBPF feature with two config options exposed, IPAddressDeny and IPAddressAllow. (I don't know if it is possible to disable it at compile time).